# Case when in sql and php

Tags: php, sql

I have a function in `php`, where i check, using `sql` if a **car garage** is booked. I have **2 types** of tables, where this garages can be stored. In the original function I use only the first table:

```
    $fields = "SELECT dd.id, h.id AS carhireid, h.name AS carhirename,
                      f.course AS courseid, c.shortname AS courseshort,
                      sd.id AS sessiondateid, sd.timestart, sd.timefinish, rd.garageid AS garagedateid, r.name AS garagename";
    $sql = "
              FROM {driver_date} dd
              JOIN {carhire_sessions_dates} sd ON sd.id = td.dateid
              JOIN {carhire_sessions} s ON s.id = sd.sessionid
              JOIN {carhire} h ON h.id = s.carhire
              JOIN {course} c ON c.id = h.course
              JOIN {alternativemanagement_garage_date} rd ON rd.dateid = td.dateid
              LEFT JOIN {carhire_garage} r ON r.id = rd.garageid
             WHERE dd.userid = ?";
    $sort = "
             ORDER BY sd.timestart DESC, sd.timefinish DESC, f.name, td.id";
```

There is also the alternative, that we have a `garageid` to each `session` in the table  `carhire_sessions`.

The names of the garages are stored in `carhire_garage`

So I want to add as follows: If `roomid` in the table `carhire_sessions` is null, then to use the `alternativemanagement_garage_date`

Comment: `SELECT IFNULL(s.roomid, rd.<columnname>, <else-condn>) ...` [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: Should it look like that `LEFT JOIN {carhire_garage} r ON r.id = SELECT IFNULL (s.garageid, rd.garageid)` ?